# How do I add starry reflections/highlights as depicted in the examples?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

[image]

[image]

See pictures above. I don't have that much experience in Photoshop at all. I tried to mess with some contrast increase on layers but I can't come up with the same result. How do I create similar highlights?

Comment: Are you trying to add the white starry blur effect?

Comment: Yes i was talking about that literally forgot to mention

Comment: Offtopic but I find it really strange that digital photography reached a stunning level of image quality but here you are, impressed by some fake light reflections.
Grab the brush, set opacity to low and start drawing them where you want them.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's already said, but if you want them to look artificial, draw them. You can speed up the process with effects. Start by inserting a new layer and draw there a white dot:

[image]

Use the smudge tool with say 50% strength and drag some branches:

[image]

Change the smudge brush size smaller and softer, draw a little more:

[image]

Duplicate the layer and insert hefty gaussian blur to the duplicate:

[image]

You may find some star effect plugin which turns with a couple of clicks a layer of white dots to a sea of artificial flares, but the shown method gives full control to you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. will surely give this a try right on